# What command line text editor can give me windows key navigation & use?

Tags: command-line, editor

EDIT: rewording to be not "opinion-based" any more.

What command line text editor in the Ubuntu repository has or can be set to allow the following behavior?

- first key presses do already start text entry.
- numpad keys are supported.
- Cursor keys to move in lines and between lines with Ctrl-right/left to move word-wise, and Ctrl-Up/DN to scroll the text up/dn on current position.
- Shift-cursor keys for marking text (letters,words,lines,multiple lines). Ctrl-Shift-Cursor, Shift-PageUn/Down accordingly
- Copy and paste with Ctrl-X/C/V
- Copy and paste with Shift-Del/Shift_Ins
- Working Ins, Del, Pos1, End, PageUp, PageDn keys like e.g. open office
- Alt-c to toggle column mode for marking. That is a very advanced function, so maybe optional.
- Tab key setting need to be definable on how many column it indents
- Ctrl-S to save

If an editor needs be configured to behave like that, it would help to know if you are aware if someone already tried/achieved something like this.

Comment: Downvoting without a comment is really lame. @catman nano is the closest thing that I've ever found for command line editing. vi makes me cry.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for your quick reply. That would be the most disappointing and sad answer I could think of. However, unless I am aware of a really good reason why that would be _not possible_ technically, I almost could not believe that nobody tackled that issue before.

Comment: I believe most people use GUI editors for power user type work, and simply get by with simple cmdline editors for convenience.  This of course excludes VI(M).

Comment: I think "tackling the issue" has been "learning the new way".

Comment: I'm in agreement with @bc2946088 if I need to actually move around, I don't use the command line. Atom, Brackets, Gedit, there's more than I could mention, all really strong tools.

Comment: The powerful editors like emacs, or even vim if you are so inclined, can of course be configured to do everything you ask for. That isn't, however, the simplest of tasks. Other editors are newbie friendly, as you put it, but don't have the features you need. Remember that command line means "for experts" in most cases. Exceptions like `nano` are quite limited. Anybody doing serious work on the command line is going to be using emacs or vim 90% of the time.

Comment: @bc2946088 I am aware that I could even remote access a GUI editor via a ssh shell (-X option). Unfortunately that fails for an ssh access from a windows computer. Also it would fail when the server has not x installed. Brandon I am sure that is the reason that it took so long before a good c++ IDE appeared for linux. Long before CodeBlocks people told me everyone on linux codes with emacs..

Comment: You unfortunately may have to start using vim/emacs, or change your workflow.  What you're looking for sits in between what the majority of users are after.  Personally, I favor sublime and git.  :)

Comment: @terdon many people mix up linux newbie with IT newbie. I have a linux server and a handful of linux clients running but still consider myself as a newbie because trains of thought between windows and linux background is just quite different. I find most docs are made either for dumb users or for people who already know the concept but forgot the details. Its interesting to note that emacs can be made to behave as I desire. Maybe the answer would be "emacs can", an I go to a new challenge to find someone with a setup file that I just need to tweak a little?

Comment: If you do choose to go the emacs route, I suggest you break this into separate requests and ask on [emacs.se] about how to configure each of them. As a general rule, if something is possible, emacs can do it but not necessarily easily. once you have it set up just the way you want it though, it's a dream. My point about newbie (your term, not mine) was that CLI editors tend to be powerful and configurable and that is usually mutually exclusive with "easy to use and configure".

Comment: @bc2946088 Change my workflow is beside the point. I just re-checked vim.tiny and got trapped in some mode and could not get out. You're positive that can be fully converted to a more nano type behaviour with my desired keys? I so, I guess I am just not accustomed yet in how far the concept of configuration can be taken in linux projects. The end-user gui staff proved rather limited so far...

Comment: You can (relatively) easily configure Vim to implement the desired keyboard shortcuts. You can `set insertmode` in your `.vimrc` to make Vim behave more like a modeless editor. Note than `vim.tiny` is not Vim, it is a very stripped-down Vi-compatible subset. To get the real Vim you need to install it.

Comment: I would like to close that question and accept an answer. The configuration of any of the given proposals is beyond the scope of the question. As I find it always a bit weird to write an own answer out of comments I'd rather have some of you provide your comment as answer,please? Some key differences between vi(including vim) and emacs, eg. conceptually would be useful to decide to which to turn first..

Comment: Some of these need configuration outside the editor itself: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346011/70524, so without configuration of both terminal and editor, the answer would be: none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't match all your list, but ne (http://ne.di.unimi.it/) is the closest out of the box. Maybe it can be configured to do everything you want. You will probably have to venture into termcap or your terminal emulator options to get eg. Windows key supported.

Comment: Wonderful find. It does almost all of the items and offers quite a bit of configuration to modify things. Its modeless, so one does not feel trapped anywhere. Checking my Requirements above, the only thing I am missing is the easy selection by SHIFT-Cursor where it highlights the selection. It uses CTRL-B to start selection, then you move the cursor to the end of the selection (without highlighting) and press e.g. CTRL-C to copy that section. Pasting works with CTRL-V or SHIFT-INS. SHIFT-Del to cut does not work though.

Answer (score 1):

I spent quite a bit of time on that issue started from the comments I got. From what I learned, the answer is

*None*.

This is based on comparing solutions to actually write a new tool.

**Background info**

The only candidates for modifications are emacs and vim. The effort for emacs would be more than to write an own editor for that spec. Vi would be installed on every Linux box and its configs can do quite a few things. But a solution would need fully  to hide multiple mode changes from the user (e.g. for marking) and would terribly mistreat vi's concept.

This is just a note about some basic vi things that helped me a lot to get a clearer outside view on the thing. There is a build in tutorial you start with 'vimtutor'. Should run on every Ubuntu box and teaches you quickly how to use vi. However, it failed to teach me how to best ''work with vi''.  I have seen countless tutorials on vi basically all talking about the same. Only this explained with examples why and how working with vi is more efficient: http://www.viemu.com/a-why-vi-vim.html. Most importantly, imho it gets clear why it is a very bad idea to use vi in any other fashion that what it had been designed for. It became clear that vi has been mastered one would use vi also in windows, because its the most superior method to modify text. Its very much as piano: Very flexible and powerful if you are good, but a long way to become good.

The designed-for-use involves

- never use cursor keys
- always have both hands at the keyboard.
- always type with 10 fingers.
- need to be able to hit any key precisely and without thinking about it
- most pressed key should be  for back from insert modes

What I am not sure if other language keyboard layouts can be used efficiently of if vi users switch to US keyboard layout..

To sum it up, the question can lead to a long and interesting tour through editors. Still I would see the benefit for have a simple common cross-plattform editor on the command line as there are many in GUI, e.g. 'gedit'. Until that I will live with 'nano'. I won't start learning vi before I am proficient with touch typing.

Answer (score 1):

This is only to add some feedback to the selected answer from @aegwaegweg.

This editor 'ne' is definitely what I has been looking for all that time. Its  90 perfect, mostly due to technical issues in the terminal. I would say, that everyone who is interested in a consistent usablilty between GUI editors (like gedit or OpenOffice) and the command line editor should use 'ne'.

Installation in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install ne
```

The only notable thing it does **not** is an intuitive selection of text with Shift-Cursor keys. However, no other editor does that. Instead it uses Ctrl-B to start marking to where ever the cursor moves. That works almost as simple as SHIFT-Cursor and is easy to remember. Only remaining drawback is that technically it seems not possible to highlight the selection block on screen. If that is solved I would score it at 100%!

Beside that it offers a ton of features including syntax highlighting and macro recording and whatsoever, so that one could use it for much more than some configuration files.

Personally, I can not understand, why Canonical does not use 'ne' as the default editor rather than nano. If Ubuntu is meant to make it easy to lean Linux, then I can see not a single advantage of nano over ne. Even the name is shorter :-)

CatMan